# Property parameter generic inferred from another property's function parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to create a TypeScript interface to represent the options to be passed to a cache checking function. The idea is fairly simple in that the `sourceFn` is the function that will be called if there's no data in the cache for the cache key. I want to determine the cache key based on the parameters passed in to the call to the `sourceFn` function. In other words, the function parameter type for `getCacheKey` should always match the function parameter type of the function passed to `sourceFn` (the parameters passed to `sourceFn` will literally be passed as-is to the `getCacheKey` function). I'm at a bit of a loss of how to do this.

Here's the sort of thing I was after (which won't work of course, but hopefully helps you to see what I'm trying to achieve):

```ts
interface CacheCheck {
  sourceFn: (...args: any) => Promise<any>
  getCacheKey: (options: Parameters<this['sourceFn']>) => string | undefined
}
```

Link to [TypeScript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMKIBYVVhBrABTijgFsBnZAbwChllSIwMB7AEwC5kAKAOn+IBzclzggAngEpkAXgB8yMeLrJBTdAiwBpCOK59+AB2JkRyIiUaQo5ADwasOCPgumA2gHIrrNh4C6ctLyyORgUKCCyAA+yACuIGwQMKAQbDQAvjQ0MPEIYMAsIMgA7sDMDti4eLYAKsgQAB6QCZQVTi4mFLJomJXOhJ3kctzGlmY1klw1nt7s-tQqUEyxUEUGvEJmbn5BCrT09MAwPKOmvGpgFTri65uS0vsH9EtgK0UeAG5wADaxKDBQFikZAIXoeFT0dL1b7kFCPJ4vN7IU4UXizNi3KDCSQQ5CZSEZLI5EB5ApFC4AVRJvTYACFvixBABRcBQG4osxUEK-QRcULhECRdKTEJhCILZ7LVbIT4-P7IAFA5AAEVpyOgGDghnI4MyNAQhVCqiY9MZLLC4m6pXKvXaeG4j3RXEp1M0qVNzNZ4gANCoLlddPoObsJQdEdKAAYAelBboAtHhdFGACRUDm8cg89IRlTpX3CrIGkBGr6-FAyY1gD3mtkO7mxXkygBGDMEccMLFCcczDY8eJx+sNLG+EF4re4pb+kiAA)

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see what is not working, copy past this interface in playground. Can you explains what is not working ?
Did you try that ? :
getCacheKey: (options: Parameters<CacheCheck['sourceFn']>) => string | undefined

Comment: @RomainTAILLANDIER - I've added a link to a playground example. What I'd like is to have the `params` argument on line 22 as a typed parameter - inferring the type from the `method` parameters arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the type of your parameters, which is any. Any match evrything. Line 4 of your code is exact, and do exactly what you want. But it is masked with the any. because anything you would pass as parameter actually extends any.

If you replace line 2 with

```
  method:(name:string, age:number) => any
```

You will have the behavior you need.

If you need to get any params, then may be you can make it generic like this  ?

```
interface CacheCheck<ARGS extends any[]> {
  sourceFn: (...args:ARGS) => Promise<any>
  getCacheKey: (...args:ARGS) => string | undefined
}
```

this leads to some changes, i tried this in the playground. Hope that could help.
Therefore there was errors on promise i think.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQGFkAsrp0gawAUEYEBbAZwB4BBAJQHEBlVKAD2jABNLUEwATwDaAXQB8qAN7BUc1OSgQsAe24AuVAAoAdHtIBzSpoYsAlKgC8kojBXkQlKNQGDxAblnyDSzEhwA0lCCmrr6MEYmTMwW1qiUEDDgBqgAPqgArjxQcOBQ3O6oAPRFqACyCIKoAEZogioZ8aoZADZo-gI%20qMpoAA52Dk6oODBQADTdKjVK0DCoSCpglI5cSII6wAC%20wMALSxCoAO4gyn44eFCEVqjUACpsnFA8fK5i4lq9pBTGGNi4%20MQvlQ7uIzJozv9LoCyMDbuJhAByRTKNQI0RWSQyeSoUYQDIwMDaPQ6Qw-W6xTFebFyPYJeZ-bjXT4wyg6HwQCFBQRhEkRShmKnUkBwbRIBkWLHUqUleZYTr5Sb8VD9eyOKCCqVyXH4wlgKCHVC2VVOLRaUaUFQtABuUAp0g1mux5stNq0qARVoQLQyaDgA3p-jQCNQAGoAzhuGZPI7sZsow65Js2C0hpLHbTLVAdC0VAYtAAiZNDdmc4KoQthgBSzAA8gA5HQJJJgAzC7mkswCmPybUE5VA1nI1TcHkd6Oa7axzybTzAGUISiCMBIYawdULpcruBZJAQECLVDsgCqy4ZACEcwYAKKQGDcyjegyaJvJMGGgZq6gvluUp1KHXup63q%20v6AAiZ7KrAcq9JQCLTjstIHOyF65jeiRVJYRwnFgEIXIQ1DCA%20GRPvEiTJBIWhpgoSjDpox6noG3Aodet6CGMgoln8XKhERBh2lIvaEgABkUYqBgAtAQwRFAAJFIvGbEJ7jbHGs4lOarQHCoIrIZeV6oI4SoqoMaAWkcCAnKgcAqHMJw6KgwC6ahrFaAi1SXuJvQqAk4m8QiZg6D0YCmkBPp2hmbTZrmBa5GAXo4lAlCadchahqgoW2gKQA)

Comment: Thanks, Romain. I was hoping this was achievable by somehow inferring the args of `getCacheKey` function from the function passed in to `sourceFn` parameter, but I think that might be asking a bit too much of TypeScript. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry that this did not work for you. Can you explain why ?